# dbms_cloud.copy_data executed but no data in table, why?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I was able to execute this snippet successfully without any errors.  However the ALERT2 table is
empty.  The .csv file has rows delimited by '|'.  Anyone know why or what I'm doing wrong?

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA(
    table_name => 'ALERT2', 
    credential_name => 'my_credential', 
    file_uri_list => 'https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/blah_blah_/dbmsc_expdata_alert_1_20230807T131603Z.csv', 
    format => json_object('type' value 'CSV', 'delimiter' value '|', 'skipheaders' value '1', 'recorddelimiter' value '''\r\n''')
 );
END;
```